# OpenTK using viewports

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'd like to use viewports with OpenTK so that I can create panels for a 2D UI around a 3D viewing area. Currently, I have only a very simple program, and am simply trying to initialize my viewports. Here is my basic game class. All I do is run it. Currently, I get a null reference error due to the added line about the two viewports, but I don't really understand why. If  not in OnLoad, should I be creating the viewports elsewhere?

*EDIT*

I changed the code to look like the following, but still am running into the same issue - there is no longer any reference to the viewports in onLoad:

```
protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        {

            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);

            //First, try to create 2 viewports
            //GL.Enable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
            GL.Viewport(windowSetup.height / 2, 0, windowSetup.width / 2, windowSetup.height / 2);
            //GL.LoadIdentity(); 
            GL.Scissor(windowSetup.height / 2, 0, windowSetup.width / 2, windowSetup.height / 2);

            //Bind shader
            Shader.Use();

            //Bind VOA
            GL.BindVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);

           
            GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, rectIndices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);


            Context.SwapBuffers();

            //Try viewport 2
            GL.Viewport(0, windowSetup.height , windowSetup.width / 2, windowSetup.height / 2);
        
            GL.Scissor(0, windowSetup.height , windowSetup.width / 2, windowSetup.height / 2);


            Shader.Use();

            GL.BindVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);

            GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, rectIndices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);

            Context.SwapBuffers();

            base.OnRenderFrame(e);
        }
```

Comment: I did some more reading and tried to apply this, but I still get a null reference exception. What I did was take those two viewport calls and split them up in my OnRenderFrame method (where I draw), basically copying everything in between except the the base.OnRenderFrame(e) - my hope was maybe it would draw a rectangle in each viewport. The error seems to be happening in onResize first, and then in OnRender again. In this case, I don't know what it's referencing that could be null. The window exists. Do I need to be initializing a new graphicsContext and binding it somehow?

Comment: I meant in the logical viewport (meaning, if I define viewport A as the top 200 pixels and viewport B as the bottom 200, it would draw a rectangle in each region since the NDC coordinates would be unique to each region). Or am I still misunderstanding what you said?

Comment: It's definitely not that I won't believe it :) I'm just struggling to understand. By moving the viewport piece into OnRenderFrame, changing the viewport, and then calling Draw again, I thought switching drawing regions was exactly what I was doing. It seems like my question must more accurately have become "how do you switch drawing regions"?

Comment: Hey, I appreciate your trying to explain it. I edited my question to reflect that I actually changed things quite a bit after your first comment - I'm not calling the two back to back anymore, and I'm calling them in the draw function. I understand if I've been annoying here, but I promise I wasn't trying to be obtuse.

Comment: I see. You are not annoying. I was just trying to make sure you understood the error. So the issue is *"[...] I get a null reference error [...]"*. I guess that `windowSetup` is  `null`.

Comment: Yup - that was it. I was looking in entirely the wrong place T.T Well, I have learned many things, and it still wouldn't have worked without what you said initially. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Perhaps you want to answer your own question and then mark it as resolved, so its no longer considered unanswered.